# Python indentation error after try:

Tags: python, indentation

I have a problem, whenever I try to run this python script on an Raspberry PI:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

I get this error:

```
 File "server.py", line 20
    try:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong here? The script is supposed to create a simple TCP/IP server, and I have no such problems with the client, so I really don't understand where is my mistake/s...

Comment: did you try removing the blank line before `try`?

Answer (score 5):

One of the unfortunate side-effects of Python's use of whitespace for denoting blocks is that sometimes you get scripts that have tabs and spaces mixed up throughout the source code.

Since this script is pretty small, you could try deleting the whitespace preceding each line's code and then reindent it properly.

Comment: To add to this, you can load up your code in Python's IDLE, select all your code and then hit `Format->Untabify Region`. After you've done that try saving your code and then try run it again.